# IK Bone setup , pole bones targets the bone wrong direction

Tags: rigging, bones, inverse-kinematics

Hey guys I have imported a character from CC and I tried to add IK bones. After added the pole bones I have a issue something like that [image]. I feel like it cause of bone rotations but I could not fix that.
Thanks for any help.
Here is blend file : [Download](https://gofile.io/d/YUHMIF)

Answer (score 0):

You need to bend the elbow a bit so that Blender knows in what direction the arm is supposed to bend.

[image]

Comment: It works but it causes another problems for example I add the copy rotation constraint to arm bones for rotating the hand smoothly . Its goes crazy

Comment: not sure what you mean, maybe re-upload the file with this new setup